# Call function with button and return response

Tags: plugins, functions, templates, callbacks

I'm trying to do the folllowing.

I have a button in my template (in templates folder of my plugin). When they press the button I want to call a function and send and id to the function.

In that function I want to create an api call and send the results back to the template. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited detail of your question something as per the following is a rough gist of what you could do.

In your theme functions.php file:

```
<?php

function handle_request () {

    if (isset($_GET['custom_id']) && isset($_GET['custom_id_nonce']) ) {


        if ( wp_verify_nonce($_GET['custom_id_nonce'], 'custom_id_action') ) {
            $id = $_GET['custom_id'];

            // FIRST
            // do something with $id

            // THEN
            // possibly redirect somewhere else or back to referrer 
            // e.g. wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() );
            // see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer
            // see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect


        } else {
            // handle failure state, nonce value is incorrect...
        }

    }

    // if here, the request was likely not for you

}

add_action( 'init', 'handle_request' );
```

In your theme template file:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_nonce_url( home_url('?custom-id=123'), 'custom_id_action', 'custom_id_nonce' );?>">CLICK ME</a>
```

In the above example, where `home_url('?custom-id=123')` is stated, you may want to change the basis for this URL to be the current URL the user is on.

Important reading:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_url
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect